# Populating an array of a private inner class in Java

Tags: java

So I have this private inner class as follows:

```
private class Exam{
   private String course;
   private double score;

   public Exam(String course, double score){
       this.course = course;
       this.score = score;
   }


   public String toString(){
       return String.format("%-25s: %1.2f", course, score);
   }
}
```

I have created an instance of this as an array

```
private Exam[] preliminaryExams = new Exam[6];
```

I did not create this class, it is part of a java learning tutorial thing, and I am having difficulty populating the array itself.  What I've been trying to do was give values to the score and course variables like so:

```
preliminaryExams[0].score = some double;
preliminaryExams[0].course = some string;
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to actually execute some code using these classes and methods I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

On the first line where I am trying to assign these values to those variables.  I'm kind of stuck at this point and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can u post stacktrace

Comment: How did that compile? score is private

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you have created the array of `Exam`, each entry in the array still points to `null`. You need to create instances of `Exam`, and assing them in your array, before you can start settings attributes on your `Exam` instances.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    preliminaryExams[i] = new Exam (someCourse, someScore);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the parameters in new Exam.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I was making some dumb mistake and repeatedly over looking it.

Answer (score 2):

After you created your array still each of those `Exam` elements points to null. So you will have to explicitly instantiate each of them as well. you could do the following.

```
for (Exam exam : preliminaryExams){
exam=new Exam(someString,someDouble);
}
```

Comment: Upthumbs for using a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

seems you haven't initialized array elements, the below line is setting the score field of an array element, not the element itself

```
preliminaryExams[0].score = some double;
```

make sure you have initialized the elements as

```
preliminaryExams[0] = new Exam(some course, some double);//call appropriate constructor here
```

before setting the score variable (any field/method of preliminaryExams in general)

Comment: `new preliminaryExams()` is wrong, `preliminaryExams` contains instances of `Exam`. I have upvoted to counter the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate an array of `Exam` but every element contained is still `null`, so you must explicitly instantiate them.

Since you have an `Exam` constructor I don't see why you don't use it:

```
private Exam[] preliminaryExams = new Exam[6];

preliminaryExams[0] = new Exam(some course, some double);
```